How to connect a remote Hive server from using JDBC and SSL?
I have below JDBC URL of Hive where I am able to connect from Beeline. I want to know how I can connect to same Hive server using Python.
Below is the command I am using from Beeline to connect to Hive:
jdbc:hive2://park-main-testthrift-lab001.ibe400.****.com:443/default;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/opt/bitnami/spark/jkscertsconvert/truststore.jks;trustStorePassword=changeit


I am able to find a solution for this
from hivejdbc import connect

conn = connect(host='park-main-testthrift-lab001.ibe400.****.com',
               port=443,
               database='default',
               driver='hive-client-2.3.7-hdfs-2.9.1-aio.jar', #replace path with hive fat jar file path location
               ssl=True,
               trust_store='truststore.jks', #replace path with your .jks file path
               trust_password='changeit')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from table")



